# How to remove _step in a column using oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column value which has _step in all the values. Can you please suggest how to remove that ?

Tried using replace function that did not work

```
select replace (_step) from schemaname_interface
```

Comment: Why didn't you  try a proper use of `replace`? `REPLACE(columnName, '_step')`

Comment: you need to use the quotes by default for Oracle to notice that you are replacing a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something similar to the following:

```
SELECT REPLACE(column_name, '_step') from schemaname_interface;
```

In this case the, the column_name in the brackets is the name of the column having the extra `_step` in all of its values.